# VB Visual studio .exe not working

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2013, release

I am making a project which i must present tomorrow. I have 6 forms, the startup was form 1 which wasn't coded by me so I thought this was the problem and deleted it. Then I set the startup form to form3, which is my main menu but its not working again. When i hit debug everything is perfect, the program is responsive, working well, but when i go to my debug folder and click the .exe it starts loading and nothing happens. Tried to run on another computer - same thing.

btw I'm using visual studio 2013

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you see the process in Task Manager? Have you checked Event Viewer to see if there's any crash logged there?

Comment: yes, i can see the program in Task Manager, but nothing in Event Viewer

Comment: Have you clean the solution before to build it ?